# jQuery UI Sortable long div oddity when placeholder is present

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In jQuery UI Sortable when creating a placeholder with a size smaller than the original item,  if you start dragging a long div down the list, it doesn't begin sorting until you get past the original height of the DIV, even though the placeholder is much smaller.

However, once you get past the end of the div, sortable kicks in and everything works normally.

The sortable code is pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "dropHelper"
    }); 
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate. Try to sort the long div down the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/YSMnX/3/

Any ideas on how to make this work correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery sortable item height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494591/jquery-sortable-item-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate. A similar question is here:

[jQuery sortable item height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494591/jquery-sortable-item-height)

Calling the refreshPositions method of sortable on start fixes the issue. The code becomes:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "dropHelper",
        start: function(e.ui){
          $(this).sortable('refreshPositions');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSMnX/5/